# Is there any system restore in Ubuntu like Windows?

Tags: gnome, 13.04, restore

I followed the instructions that in [Install gnome 3.8 in Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.ubuntukiller.com/2013/03/how-to-installupgrade-gnome-38-in.html) and then after restarting many programmes stopped working and fails to start like Rhythombox / Cairo dock / Totem / Weather / Empathy

Is there any way to cancel what I did or remove installed packages?
They're a lot of packages (about 90 MB) and I can't `purge` them because I can not remember them all.

Comment: @Radu The OP is asking if there is a way to restore system to a previous state, and not how to backup/restore a system.

Comment: yes, we call it making a backup :=)

Comment: @Mitch Sorry, I rushed

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of recently installed packages that were installed via apt-get or Software Center by following command:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep "\ install\ "
```

you can see all the packages from it and then remove them.

Answer (score -2):

1. Backup any data that you want.
2. Shut down your PC.
3. Insert installation disk/usb turn on PC.
4. Bring up boot menu, set to boot from CD-ROM/USB.
5. set to delete the other ubuntu/ delete partition.

this is the ubuntu equivalent of a system restore.

Comment: This is poor, don't do it.